# Fundamental group of tetrahedron

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, cw-complexes

Consider the following double tetrahedron

[image]

We glue $DCE$ to $CBA$, $CBE$ to $BDA$ and $BDE$ to $DCA$. We call the resulting space $L$. I want to find a cell-structure on $L$ with only two $0$-cells and compute the fundamental group of $L$.

I glue the lines $DC$ on $CB$ on $BD$, $BA$ on $CE$, $DE$ on $CA$ and $DA$ on $BE$. I identify the points $B,C,D$ and $A,E$, such that we are left with two $0$-cells, four $1$-cells, three 2-cells and 1 3-cell. I know that $\pi_1(L)=\pi_1(L^1)/{\langle \text{something}\rangle}$, where $\pi_1(L^1)\cong F({a,b,c})$, the fundamental group with three generators. I still have to determine "something", which are the relations. How can I find those?

Comment: If I were you, I will try the following (I don't know if this works, but it should): Given some orientations of edges based on how you glue the surfaces, then consider the four 1-cells as generators. The three 2-cells should give you some relations, and use the relations should reduce 4 generators into 3, and give you the "something"

Comment: FIY, in Hatcher's book, question 1.2.14 is solved in exactly the same way I mentioned.

Comment: That is also how I wanted to do it, I have the four generators but what are the relations?

Comment: can you write down the 2 cells in terms of your generators?

Comment: Actually, I can't find the generators. Are there  3 or 4? And are they the identified edges?

Comment: can you find the four 1 cells? These should be generators of the fundamental group. However, the 2 cells should give you some relations among the generators.

Comment: Yes I find 4 1-cells, namely the glued sides $DC,CB,BD$ let's call it a, the glued side $BE,DA$ let's call it b, the sides $CE, BA$, let's call it c and the sides $CA,DE$ let's call it d. So, $\pi_1(L)=F(\{a,b,c,d\})/ \langle \text{relation}\rangle $. The first 2-cell is $DCE$ glued on $CBA$. What relation does the first 2-cell give us?

Comment: great, but so far I suppose it gives nothing unless you assign some orientations to your edges.

Comment: E.g. CA and AC are different

Comment: if you give directions, then $DC\to CE\to ED$ should give you 1 in the 2 cell

Comment: Let $a:=DC\to CB\to BD$, $b:=CE\to DA$, $c:=DE\to CA$, $d:=DA\to BE$ where we meant "glue with given orientation" by $\to$, then $\pi_1(L)=F(\{a,b,c,d\})/\langle abc^{-1},adb^{-1},acd^{-1}\rangle$

Comment: Well, the orientation in my mind maybe simpler. Let $a=D\to C$ and $b=C\to E$ and $c=E\to D$. Then $abc=1$. You can use this orientation to obtain other orientations (edges glued together should have the same orientation). Then the three 2-cells give what you want

Comment: Don't you nead a fourth orientation, $d=B\to E$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90580/discussion-between-james-and-abigail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**: Let us give orientations to the edges. Say $a=DC,b=CE,c=ED,d=BE$. Then after gluing (the orientation should match when gluing edges.) we have the following:
\begin{align*}
a&=DE=BE=BD=CB\\
b&=CE=BA\\
c&=ED=CA\\
d&=BE=DA
\end{align*}
(Notice that $DE=-ED$ and so on)

**Step 2**: There are two $0$-cells: point $P$ and $Q$, where $P=B=C=D$ and $Q=A=E$.(again this is by just observing the gluing.)

Let us now see what are the possible generators of the fundamental group.(I am to lazy to use Tikz, so I will try to avoid using graphs. Draw the picture by hand if you want, it might help you understand)

The idea is that, look at the possible links from $P$ to $Q$. Then there are four possible links (after gluing of course). In fact, the above relations give you the links. Namely:

---

$a$ is a loop from $P$ to $P$,

$b$ is a path from $P$ to $Q$,

$c$ is a path from $Q$ to $P$,

$d$ is a path from $P$ to $Q$.

---

Thus, together, we get $4$ loops: $a$, $bc$,$-bd$, and $cd$. Thus you have the set of generators of $\pi_1(L)$.

Then the **question** is that, how can we find the relations among the generators? Also is it possible that one (or more) generator can be obtained by other generators?

Thus you need **step 3**, Which I suppose you should try yourself. Write down the possible surfaces bounded by your orientated edges, and see which loop gives you $1$ in the $2$-cell. For example, the surface $DCB$ is obtained by $a^3$. So $a^3=1,$ and so on.